# openssl CMS decryption fails

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, content-management-system, smime

openssl cms -decrypt -in cms.txt -recip my_cert.pem -inkey private_key.pem

Error reading S/MIME message 140064210231744:error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:../crypto/asn1/asn_mime.c:391

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the correct header of your cms.txt ?

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what in `cms.txt` is. So, let me create my own.

First, I create the recipient's keypair with [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert):

```
➤ mkcert --client mail@example.org
Created a new local CA at "/home/user/.local/share/mkcert" 
Warning: the local CA is not installed in the system trust store! ⚠️
Warning: the local CA is not installed in the Firefox and/or Chrome/Chromium trust store! ⚠️
Warning: the local CA is not installed in the Java trust store! ⚠️
Run "mkcert -install" to avoid verification errors ‼️

Created a new certificate valid for the following names 
 - "mail@example.org"

The certificate is at "./mail@example.org-client.pem" and the key at "./mail@example.org-client-key.pem" ✅
➤ ls -1
'mail@example.org-client-key.pem'
'mail@example.org-client.pem'
```

Let's create the `cms.txt`:

```
➤ echo "my secret message: blablub" | \
     openssl cms \
       -encrypt -aes256 -from user@example.com \
       -to user@example.org -subject "The secret" \
       -out cms.txt mail@example.org-client.pem
➤ cat cms.txt
To: user@example.org
From: user@example.com
Subject: The secret
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

You have to apply decryption only on the part which comes after the empty line:

```
➤ sed -n '/^$/,/^$/p' cms.txt | base64 -d | \
     openssl cms -inform DER -decrypt \
       -inkey mail@example.org-client-key.pem
my secret message: blablub
```